# Shortcut for quick actions in Microsoft Word for macOS

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

My development IDE's have a single quick-action shortcut that brings up a dialog box in which one can search for specific commands to be applied. Here is what the looks like in `Pycharm` when hitting <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>:

[image]

Does MS Word have such a thing?  I really do not want to have to take fingers off the keyboard and hunt around that Ribbon.

Comment: Not really what you asked for but the [Microsoft Web Pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#PickTab=macOS) has all the shortcuts on it..